# How is the signed rank statistic defined in Matlab?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, matlab, ranking

1. Given a sequence of sample points $X_1, \dots, X_n$, I am trying to
   find a Matlab function to

   - compute the signed rank statistic defined as $$ \sum_{i=1}^n sign(X_i) r_i $$ where $r_i$ is the rank of $|X_i|$ in $|X_1|,
         \dots, |X_n|$, and $sign(X_i)$ returns $1$ if $X_i >0$ and $-1$ if
     $X_i <0$.
   - and also to compute the p-value of this signed rank statistic.
2. The function I suspect to be relevant is [`signrank`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/signrank.html#bti40ke-8) in Matlab.
   Matlab signrank function takes the minimum between  the sum of the ranks of positive differences and  the sum of the ranks of negative differences. In [the implementation of signrank function](http://code.google.com/p/gene-armada/source/browse/trunk/Matlab+Altered/signrank.m?r=2)

   ```
   % Compute signed rank statistic (most extreme version)
   w = sum(tierank(neg));
   w = min(w, n*(n+1)/2-w);
   ```

**Questions:**

1. I was wondering why Matlab signrank function takes the minimum
   between  the sum of the ranks of positive differences and  the sum
   of the ranks of negative differences? I checked the following
   references listed in the source file of signrank.m, but haven't
   found them taking the minimum as the signed rank statistic.

   ```
   %   References:
   %      [1] Hollander, M. and D. A. Wolfe.  Nonparametric Statistical
   %          Methods. Wiley, 1973.
   %      [2] Gibbons, J.D.  Nonparametric Statistical Inference,
   %          2nd ed.  M. Dekker, 1985.
   ```
2. Is the p value provided by Matlab signrank function, same as the p
   value I want?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2):

You are right that the MATLAB `signrank` function returns something other than what you defined. It returns the sum of the ranks for the points with positive sign. Presumably this would have the same p-value as your statistic, since one is a function of the other (and the sample size).

You could use the `tiedrank` and `sign` functions to compute your statistic directly.

Comment: Thanks! (1) "It returns the sum of the ranks for the points with positive sign", so if flipping the signs of the points, the signed rank statistic value may change. But I found that `[p,h,stats] = signrank(x)` and `[p,h,stats] = signrank(-x)` return the same signed rank statistic value. (2) "You could use the tiedrank and sign functions to compute your statistic directly." How shall I compute the p-value next?

Comment: Also I updated my question a little with new findings.

Answer (score 1):

`[r p]=corr(X,Y,'type','spearman')` will calculate a `p-value` by comparing ranks between X and Y.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question a little with new findings.